# How to do JSON parsing in GRPC micro-services in iOS using Swift 4.1 (Xcode 10)?

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-cloud-platform, grpc

I am working on a project, that used GRPC microservices. Normally GRPC used protobuf as his default method to serialized data. But, we are using JSON as placed of protobuf. In general, we defined message and services in protobuf and complied with **protoc** , then merged generated file with the project. But somehow google made tough to merged JSON in GRPC. I thought Google should make a documentation like this (https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json) for iOS developer too. But unfortunately, there is no separate documentation in Swift. I found it hard to used JSON type in GRPC. How will I call methods in **CLIENT-SIDE** code in Swift?

I want to pass two variable (data: String, idToken: String) i.e defined in Request struct after that services should give me a **Response**. In that way, I would understand both get and post method used in GRPC.

https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-with-json , In this link, we can check how java works with JSON+GRPC. I am adding this java code example for more understanding oh what I want to make in Swift, Maybe it will do some help.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import io.grpc.MethodDescriptor;


public class UserManagerRpcGson {
    private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "url";
    public static final class Request {
        public String data;
        public String idToken;
    }

    public static final MethodDescriptor<Request, Response> REGISTER_METHOD =
            MethodDescriptor.newBuilder(
                    marshallerFor(Request.class),
                    marshallerFor(Response.class))
                    .setFullMethodName(
                            MethodDescriptor.generateFullMethodName(SERVICE_NAME, "registerUser"))
                    .setType(MethodDescriptor.MethodType.UNARY)
                    .setSampledToLocalTracing(true)
                    .build();

    static <T> MethodDescriptor.Marshaller<T> marshallerFor(Class<T> clz) {
        return new MethodDescriptor.Marshaller<T>() {
            @Override
            public InputStream stream(T value) {
                return new ByteArrayInputStream(GsonUtil.gson.toJson(value, clz).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            }

            @Override
            public T parse(InputStream stream) {
                return GsonUtil.gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8), clz);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide examples of what you have tried. The json response structure. Then we should be able to give you some targeted help.

Comment: Hey @BenAvery, Sir I edited the post and add some code. This code is in java. As I told in post, I had no idea how to do it in swift, iOS.